# Unusual SASS Errors

Tags: sass

Today, suddenly, I began receiving unusual and unexpected errors when executing SASS Watch:

```
(Line 4: Invalid property: "Backtrace:" (no value).)

error globals.css (Line 43: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.)

error globals.css (Line 52: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.)
```

I was editing this document yesterday and didn't encounter these errors. While the server is a shared server managed by my hosting provider Site5; I have no knowledge or reason to suspect changes to the servers configuration have been made. And Those lines do not use spaces for indention, line 4 is empty, and manually deleting those lines entirely doesn't change the output.

Can anyone enlighten me to what I'm missing here?

Thank you.